# Javascript find the Area of a Trapezoid plus don't allow the user to enter non numerical values

Tags: javascript

I am working a basic Javascript program to calculate the area of a trapezoid with given the variable names and the formula for area of a trapezoid which I have figured out mostly. The part I am having trouble is making it so it re-prompts the user for the variable if they enter a value that is not a number. I have tried the following as well as alert instead of prompt:

```
while (isNaN(variablename)==true);
{
   variablename = prompt("please enter a numerical value");
}
```

This does nothing but run through the loop regardless of if it isNaN or not. The following is what I have so far:

```
var topLen = Number(prompt("Enter a Number for the Top Length of the Trapezoid"));
var botLen = Number(prompt("Enter a Number for the Bottom Length of the Trapezoid"));
var trapHeight = Number(prompt("Enter a Number for the Height of the Trapezoid"));

var trapArea = ((.5*trapHeight)*(topLen+botLen));

document.write("The area of a trapezoid with a tip length of " + topLen + ", 
bottom length of "     + botLen + " and the height of " + trapHeight + " is " + trapArea +".");
```

Please also keep in mind that I cannot use and functions, except for isNaN() as we have not been taught them yet.

Comment: Can you use `isNaN()`?

Comment: Yes we can, that's the only function we have been taught, I forgot

Comment: You have an errant semicolon at the end of your while loop. This is causing the block following it to not run.

Comment: wow thanks! I've been trying to figure this out all day. I removed the semicolon from each while loops and added parseint() like Scott said. Thank you all you guys saved my grade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the two pieces you need:

1. A loop to keep requesting a value until it is a valid number
2. A way to convert a string to a number, such that isNan() can be used to see if the string represented a number.

You just need to combine them: convert the string you prompt for into a number before testing it.